# How do I properly format happy when dealing with robust AST declarations?

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, happy

I am trying to create a lexxer and parser for a language and I'm having difficulty understanding the exact syntax when it comes to some more "robust" abstract syntax tree definitions.

The issue in question is :

```
fun_declaration : FUN ID param_list ':' type '{' fun_block '}' 
                 { M_fun ($2, [$3], $5, $7) }
fun_block : declarations fun_body                   { [$1] [$2] }
```

The definition of M_fun is as follows:

```
M_fun (String,[(String,Int,M_type)],M_type,[M_decl],[M_stmt])
```

So as you can see, $2 relates to string, $3 will return a [(String,Int,M_Type)], $5 will return an M_Type, but $7 is where the issue lies.  It's to return a [M_decl], [M_stmt].  Is the above syntax correct?  The happy file compiles without complaint, but when I compile the .hs file after, it explodes with ~2000 lines of errors, and I think things like this are the cause.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `fun_block` production to return an `([M_decl], [M_stmt])`, you need to construct one properly in the associated haskell code. You have:

```
{ [$1] [$2] }
```

and this is not a valid expression. I believe you should have:

```
{ ( [$1], [$2] ) }
```

You then need to change the type definition of `M_fun` to

```
M_fun (String,[(String,Int,M_type)],M_type,([M_decl],[M_stmt]))
```

so that the last argument to `M_fun` (i.e. `$7` has the same type as that returned by `fun_block`).

Comment: Thank you, but wouldn't this return an data type of type M_fun (String,[(String,Int,M_type)],M_type,([M_decl],M_stmt])) instead of M_fun (String,[(String,Int,M_type)],M_type,[M_decl],[M_stmt])?  Or will haskell figure out that they aren't paired by the data type it's trying to make?

Comment: It will return something of type `( [ A ], [ B ] ) where `A` is the type of `declarations` i.e. `$1`, and `B` is the type of `fun_body` i.e. `$2`. I don't know if this is the type that you want, because you haven't posted the type declaration for the `fun_block` production. In any case, you must make sure that the type of the expression in the haskell code of the `fun_block` production matches the type given in the type definition of `fun_block` (if any), and matches the type required in all places that make use of the `fun_block` definition.

Comment: Since you define the type of `fun_declaration` as `M_fun (String,[(String,Int,M_type)],M_type,[M_decl],[M_stmt])`, you cannot construct an `M_fun` with the expression `M_fun ($2, [$3], $5, $7)`, as the tuple given to `M_fun` should be 5-ary, not 4-ary. However, you may be able to fix this by changing the definition of `M_fun` to `M_fun (String,[(String,Int,M_type)],M_type,([M_decl],[M_stmt]))`. Note the additional brackets around what was previously the last two arguments to `M_fun`, making `M_fun` 4-ary rather than 5-ary, (I think) making it match the type that `fun_block` is passing it.